# Regarding: PKCS7, X509 and DER

Tags: openssl

I am novice to the "World of cryptography". I started working with OPENSSL.
I need some information and basically I do have some doubts.
I have a DER format file. I read the file using following command,
"openssl x509 -inform DER -in filename.der -text" I got what I supposed to be.

Following things I wanted to know:

1. What is the difference between PKCS7, DER and X509 ?
   (My understanding is, DER is format, X509 is certificate, and PKCS7 is the standard)
2. I wrote a test file which accepts the DER file and outputs the version, serial number, Subject, Validity date before and Validity date after, But I am unable to get certificate verified. Following is the API Used.

   int i = X509_verify(X509 *x509 , X509_get_pubkey(X509 *x509));
   But 'i' value is 'i' < 0(zero) This is why I am getting "Signature verification problems".
   How to overcome this?
3. In My test file I am unable to read the "Signature Algorithm", "Subject Public Key Info", "X509v3 extensions" and "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" to "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

Please give some inputs.

Thanks in Advance.
openSid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PKCS#7 is a cryptography standard published by RSA Security in 1993 that deals with data that has cryptography applied to it. Its a standard for how to package data securely. PKCS#7 references the X.509 standard, as the source for certificate formatting.

X.509 is a wide ranging security standards document published in 1998 which includes amongst other things, certificate file formats.

X.509 specifies that certificates should be encoded using the Distinguished Encoding Rules of the ASN.1 (documented in the X.208 and now X.608) standard, first published in 1984.

So, DER says how to encode some strings and numeric source data into a binary format,
X.509 says which data needs to go into a digital certificate, and 
PKCS#7 says how that certificate should be used, to digitally sign a message.

---

Privacy Enhanced Mail - some kind of tool released before OpenSSL - needed to pass PKCS#7 "wrapped" data around in email messages that at the time were exchanged on systems that only supported 7 bit ASCII characters - "PEM" created the standard of using Base64 to encoded the X.509 certificates required by PKCS#7, and storing the base64 inside -----BEGIN ???----- -----END ???----- where ??? can be a RSA PRIVATE KEY, PSA PUBLIC KEY, CERTIFICATE etc.

Comment: FYI: pkcs7 der/pem files can bundle many certificates where a x509 der/pem can't bundle unrelated chains together. Thats why pkcs7 is consider a bulk export today etc. Example when the PE32 file of windows is signed with a 'code signing' cert, it contains two chains in the OPTIONS Security header, both the 'codesign' and the 'timestamp' chains in one der format data block.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS Components are PKCS#1, PKCS#5, PKCS#7, PKCS#8, PKCS#9, PKCS#10, and PKCS#12, PKCS standards are specifications produced by RSA Laboratories in cooperation with secure-system developers worldwide for the purpose of accelerating the deployment of public-key cryptography.

A user can request a certificate from a Certificate Authority is for that user to send his or her public key in a PKCS#10 object to the CA.Once the request is approved, the CA issues a certificate that is wrapped in a PKCS#7-formatted object.

PKCS#7 defines a standard format for data that has had cryptography applied to it,PKCS#7 specifies only a data format, not the choice of any specific algorithms (X509)

X.509 certificate is a public key packaged with information about the certificate owner and issuer